# Splash screen xml shows nothing

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I followed the [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) to create `launch_screen.xml` under `drawable` folder.
However, there is nothing showed in `design` part. How to fix it?
`ic_launcher_new_foreground.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_new_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_new_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

`color.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="blue">#188DDC</color>
</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It says in the code you shared in the screenshot mipmap instead of @drawable.

Could that be the reason? Please let me know. If it is not, can look further for the solution.

Comment: Can you please share your styles.xml and MainActivity?